# Calling getters and writing to a txt file

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve something.

I have been trying and i think im heading in the right direction but could use a little help.
Below is what i have done and what i am having trouble understanding is how to implement the: (filename, profile_list) to avoid the typeerror for positional arguments as im confused on how to pass these (Im new to python so sorry if this is a silly question or something really simple)

Im also unsure if im calling the getters in the correct way?.

Profile_list is a list that contains data that i am trying to write to the file.

is what i have so far heading in the right direction?

```
def write_to_file(filename, profile_list):
    
    output_file = open("new_profiles.txt", "w")

    for profile_obj in profile_list: 
        first = profile_obj.get_given_name()
        family = profile_obj.get_family_name()
        email = profile_obj.get_email()
        gender = profile_obj.get_gender()
    
        output_file.write(' '.join((f'{first} {family}'))) 

    file.close()
```

Im attempting to write the data that is stored(im calling the getters to get this data) to a txt file like this for example:

```
First Family email@email.com M
```

so far i was just puting the name and last name in the output_file.write just so i can test if i could get it to write to the file

Answer (score 0):

Some subtle changes:

1. use the `with` satetment for file handling.
2. remove unnecessary `join` and add newline at the end of each record.

```py
def write_to_file(filename, profile_list):
    
    with open("new_profiles.txt", "w") as output_file:

        for profile_obj in profile_list: 
            first = profile_obj.get_given_name()
            family = profile_obj.get_family_name()
            email = profile_obj.get_email()
            gender = profile_obj.get_gender()
    
            output_file.write(f'{first} {family} {email} {gender}\n')
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. \n does make more sense. Thank you for some changes